# Communication between different activities

Tags: android

Currently working on android application which is social application just like Facebook.
What I'm trying to do is how to show like when user goes from home feeds page to feeds details then from there to another feeds related page and like the post there.

For example let's consider :

```
A -> Feeds page(feed id 1, with image containing two person me and my friend)
B -> Feeds Details Page(Showing that image)
C -> My friend's profile
```

A user navigate from feeds page to my friend's profile and like the image there. How should I render the like when user again comeback to feed page.

I try to do this by activity for result but that is not efficient for multiple activities.

Answer (score 1):

one way is to use local lroadcasts

for example in your feed activity:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
    .registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //update your UI here
        }
    }, new IntentFilter("photoLiked"));
```

and when a photo is liked send a broadcast:

```
 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
       .sendBroadcast(new Intent("photoLiked"))
```

Comment: Yep and make sure you're passing an `id` or something with the Intent

Answer (score 0):

You could use an Event Bus like Otto.

Easy usage and everything is very loose coupled.

http://square.github.io/otto/